# awk and field splitting parameters

Tags: database, sed, field, awk

i have a file like this

```
fld1="the farm 10" fld3="the farm 1.0" img="https://urlshortener/45R6wmN.png" titlefld4="draw4"
fld1="testing explosives" fld3="testing explosives v15" img="https://urlshortener/45R6wmN.png" titlefld4="draw4"
fld1="law cases" fld3="law cases v5" img="https://urlshortener/45R6wmN.png" titlefld4="draw4"
fld1="history trails" fld3="history trails v4 " img="https://urlshortener/vrjnrethrt.png" titlefld4="draw4"
fld1="climbing dumber" fld3="climbing dumber v1.2" img="https://urlshortener/ervwyntuny.png" titlefld4="draw4"
fld1="pluming 4 dumbs" fld3="pluming 4 dumbs v2.0" img="https://urlshortener/rthvbyh.png" titlefld4="draw4"
```

what i need is to input this info into a database, so i need to separate the fields.
the logic is that the field starts with some text(field name) and ends after the 2nd "
desired output of 1st line using | as field separator (anything would do)

```
fld1="the farm 10"|fld3="the farm 1.0"|img="https://urlshortener/45R6wmN.png" titlefld4="draw4"
```

try to use awk `awk -v OFS="|" '{$1=$1}1'` but it splits on every space

how can i achieve this (awk, sed or anything else to compile a automated script...)

Comment: perhaps `sed 's/" /"|/g'`

Comment: Do you have quotes inside your quotes? (Escaped or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\S+="[^"]*")\s+/\1|/g' file
```

This replaces space(s) following a field by a `|` globally throughout the file.

Comment: oguzismail answer also works but yours is more universal cause it can be applied to files with more fields and a slightly different structure without any tweak.

Comment: @LcrossPortugal what makes you think oguzismail's script would need tweaked in situations where potongs doesn't? Neither script produces the expected output in your question and IMHO it'd be far easier to tweak the awk script to do so than the sed script.

Comment: for example add a new field in the beginning and awk deletes it sed doesn't.
that was exactly what i did... and compare final results ....
i do know awk is very powerful and probably th best tool for this kind of job...but the final output decided for me...

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU awk this way:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FPAT="[^= ]+=\"[^\"]+\""; OFS="|" } { $1=$1 } 1'
```